# ActiveMQ 5.1.5: individualDeadLetterStrategy not working as expected

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to configure a DLQ per queue based on the following config
as described [here](https://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling):

```xml
<!-- Set the following policy on all queues using the '>' wildcard -->
<policyEntry queue=">">
   <deadLetterStrategy>
      <!--
         Use the suffix 'DLQ.' for the destination name, and make
         the DLQ a queue rather than a topic
      -->
      <individualDeadLetterStrategy queueSuffix=".DLQ" useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
   </deadLetterStrategy>
</policyEntry>
```

I'm using virtual topics so have a topic named like

`VirtualTopic.Things.1.0`

which means I can create a Queue called

`Consumer.Me.VirtualTopic.Things.1.0`

to automatically subscribe to this topic.

The `individualDeadLetterStrategy` above creates a DLQ that has the name:

`ActiveMQ.DLQ.Queue.Consumer.Me.VirtualTopic.Things.1.0.DLQ`

I was hoping for simply

`Consumer.Me.VirtualTopic.Things.1.0.DLQ`

Are my expectations correct? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `queuePrefix` is `ActiveMQ.DLQ.Queue.` and the default `queueSuffix` is empty. Since you're using `queueSuffix=".DLQ"` and not defining `queuePrefix` then it is creating queues with the default prefix and your custom suffix resulting in `ActiveMQ.DLQ.Queue.<queueName>.DLQ`. If you don't want to use the default prefix you should set `queuePrefix=""`, e.g.:

```xml
<individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="" queueSuffix=".DLQ" useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
```